# How to handle ADOdb Execute return value

Tags: php, adodb

I've found several tutorials which have similar code like the following:

```
   $sql = "select * from users";

   $result =  $conn1->Execute($sql);

   if ($result==false) {
      print 'error' . $conn1->ErrorMsg() . '<br>';
   } else {   
      print_r($result->GetRows());          
   }
```

But how can $result ever be false? If I add a where clause which can not be fulfilled the else-branch is still taken since $result contains the column titles. **Examples:**

```
"select * from users"; // Select the whole table data
echo "$result";
```

leads to

```
id,username,password 1,peter,geheim 2,sabine,secret 3,thorsten,qwertz
```

Whereas

```
"select * from users where username = 'does not exist'";
echo "$result";
```

leads to

```
id,username,password
```

Therefore result is never false. What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

The Execute method returns `false` if the query itself fails, and not if it has 0 results.

If you want to check if the query returned any results you can use the RecordCount method.

```
$rows = $conn1->Execute($sql);
if ($rows->RecordCount() > 0) {
    // Do something with your rows
} else {
     // Nothing returned
}
```